Swift Alamofire: why when I upload multipart/form-data I always get "Request Body None"
I'm trying to upload a multipart/form-data request using Alamofire in Swift to my backend running on localhost:8080. When I send the request, the server response is a 403 error, and the request body always shows as None. However, when I perform the same request using Postman, everything works fine, and I receive the expected 200 OK response.
Here's the code I'm using with Alamofire:
    func createLotto(newLotto: NewLottoData, token: String) {
        print(newLotto)
        
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
     
            multipartFormData.append(newLotto.nomeLotto.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "nomeLotto")
            multipartFormData.append(newLotto.budgetLotto.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "budgetLotto")
            multipartFormData.append(newLotto.descrizioneLotto.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "descrizioneLotto")
            multipartFormData.append(newLotto.emailUtente.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "emailUtente")
            
      
            let prodottiListData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newLotto.prodottiList)
            let prodottiListJSONString = String(data: prodottiListData, encoding: .utf8)!
            print(prodottiListJSONString)
            multipartFormData.append(prodottiListJSONString.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "prodottiList")
            

            multipartFormData.append(newLotto.imgCopertina, withName: "imgCopertina", fileName: "copertina.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            
         
            for (index, image) in newLotto.prodottiImmagini.enumerated() {
                multipartFormData.append(image, withName: "prodottiImmagini[\(index)]", fileName: "image_\(index).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }
        },
        to: "http://localhost:8080/lotti/createLotto",
        method: .post,
        headers: [
            "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"
        ]).responseDecodable(of: GenericResponse.self) { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
    }





import UIKit

struct NewLottoData: Encodable {
    let nomeLotto: String
    let budgetLotto: String
    let descrizioneLotto: String
    let emailUtente: String
    let prodottiList: [NewProdotto]
    let imgCopertina: Data
    let prodottiImmagini: [Data]
}


In my debug output, I always see [Body]: None, which suggests that the request body isn't being sent correctly. I've confirmed that all data (strings and images) exist before uploading, and I've tried setting various Content-Type headers, but nothing seems to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/KxxKnGyI.png)
Here’s some additional information:
It’s not an issue with the token. I can confirm that it’s valid.
I’ve printed out all the data before sending the request, and everything looks correct.
The images are initially of type UIImage, and I can display them in the app before sending the request. I’ve converted the images using .pngData()! to Data type, and that seems to work fine.
Alamofire version 5.9.1
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I tried uploading the form data using Alamofire with the provided parameters, including text fields and images, expecting the request body to be properly sent, just like it works in Postman. I was expecting a 200 status code response from the server and the data to be processed as it is in Postman.
However, what I got instead was a 403 Forbidden error, and the debug output indicates that the request body is empty (None)

"I’ve converted the images using .pngData()!" I'm not sure that's the reason of your issue, but you say that's in a jpg in the mimeType, which is contradictory.

"[Body]: None" Is that from Alamofire in Console? I wonder if that sometimes in case of MultiformParData as it usually can't be translated as such into a String, it won't show it. Rather check the content-length header value.

Note Apple requires https connection. To use http, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity"
in your Info.plist to allow http connection to the server. Have you done that?

Thanks @Larme, I corrected the mimeType but the problem still persist.
"[Body]: None" yes it's from Alamofire.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Yes, I did

Alamofire's multipart uploads, and uploads in general, use URLSessionUploadTasks under the hood. This means it won't use body data but instead stream the upload from a file or memory. In the case of multipart uploads, it could be either, depending on the overall size of the payload (large payloads are written to disk first).
